# Cygwin Wrong Root path

Tags: cygwin

Cygwin always handles the wrong path

If I use commands like `pwd`, `ls`, it will print correctly

```sh
# use pwd
> /home/XXX
```

But when I want CRUD, or something, it will use the wrong path

```sh
#use touch
> touch m
> echo ls | grep "m" #got nil
> echo ls /cygdrive/c | grep "m" #got file, m

#use git
> git clone "xxx.git" . #also clone into C:\xxx folder
> ls | grep "xxx" #got nil
```

Run `mount`

```sh
C:/cygwin64/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin64/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin64 on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
D: on /cygdrive/d type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

Run `echo $HOME`

```sh
/home/XXX
```

Comment: `echo ls | grep "m"` is not doing what you are thinking. Try just `ls | grep "m"`

Comment: @matzeri this isn't the point

Comment: than is not clear what you want and what is your problem. If your Home is the same of `/cygdrive/c` you have a very strange system

Comment: @matzeri If you regard HOME as an io, then its output is normal, but the input is wrong

Answer (score 0):

it works fine for me :

```
$ pwd
/home/Marco
$ touch m
$ ls -l  m
-rw-r--r-- 1 Marco Kein 0 Apr 13 16:45 m
```

if you have a different outcome, may be you have a wrong `touch` on your PATH
before the one in `/usr/bin` or some strange `alias`

```
$ which -a touch
/usr/bin/touch
/cygdrive/d/utility/touch
```